# Configurar una instancia de un sitio para el desarrollo local con Docker y docker-compose

Tags: git, github, docker, docker-compose

Estoy tratando de correr la aplicación de Poonton de Mozilla en mi computadora.

Siguiendo la siguiente documentación:
https://mozilla-pontoon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/setup.html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya instale Docker.

Ya clone el repositorio en mi computadora(el paso 1); sin embargo no logro correr el comando 2 (el paso 2), me pide ejecutar desde la raiz del repositorio

```
   make build
```

Lo estoy corriendo de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya pude instalar make con cygdrive;
sin embargo a la hora de correr make build ahora marca:

```
make: /cygdrive/c/Program: No se encontró el programa
make: *** [Makefile:38: build] Error 127
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo makefile tiene declarado esto en las siguientes lineas;
¿ahora puede ser algo relacionado con Docker?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error que mostraba anteriormente con la leyenda Makefile:38 ERROR 127, creo que se debia por que make no estaba en la variable de entorno PATH; al agregar la variable ahora marca lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ah ok, en mingw64 revisa que si tengas instalado `make`, yo recomendaría usar WSL o https://cmder.net/ que viene un poco mas completo que mingw64 para tener diferentes comandos de unix.

Comment: Solo encontre un archivo en una subcarpeta de GIT que se llama make.vim e instale cmder.net pero me marca C:\Users\ADATA\Documents\GitHub\pontoon (master -> origin)
λ make build
"make" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Comment: es por lo mismo que no tienes make instalado, es raro que el cmder full no lo traiga (yo lo tengo instalado hace 2 años igual y venia) , debes bajar make 
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm para hacer funcionar el makefile que viene en pontoon. Otra forma seria instalar https://chocolatey.org/ que es el gestor de paquetes de Windows y desde ahi instalar make con choco install make

Comment: Ya pude instalar make con cygdrive, sin embargo ahora marca otros errores ,actualice el post con estos nuevos errores.

Comment: ah ya vi, en cygwin no compartes el path del ejecutable de docker y docker-compose por eso en la terminal de cygwin  no encuentra dicho programa. No se si se pueda meter docker & docker-compose al cygwin

Comment: El mismo link que indicaste https://mozilla-pontoon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/setup.html, en sus pre-requisitos postula que para Windows hay que utilizar MozillaBuild en lugar de Make para ese paso.

Comment: Por el problema de las rutas te podría ayudar usar powershell en lugar de MINGW, para hacer el make

Answer (score 0):

El error puede ser causado si usas cygwin en su versión de 32 bits , pero en este caso veo que usas la versión 64 bits.

Al ver los mensajes que obtienes al realizar

```
$make build
```

el error en realidad es provocado porque el path que indicas no es "válido", la razón es que contiene espacios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para evitar este problema es importante que cuando instales `cygwin`, este no sea instalado en un directorio que contenga espacio en el nombre de la ruta, evita por ejemplo instalarlo dentro de:

```
C:\Program Files\
```

puedes usar otro directorio, en mi caso yo lo instalé dentro de "C:\cygwin64":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además asegura que la ruta de `cywin` se encuentre especificada en las variables de entorno, en este caso la variable `PATH`.

Comment: de hecho lo tengo instalado como lo tienes: C:\cygwin64

Comment: Indica que lo trata de leer desde \Program Files\ de hecho tuve que reinstalarlo,  en la variable de ambiente "PATH" tienes configurado C:\cygwin64 ?

Comment: acabo de agregar al a variable de ambiente PATH C:\GnuWin32\bin, actualice el post con los nuevos errores

Comment: si usas Windows, debes cerrar y abrir la consola el `PATH` no carga igual que en GNU/Linux @NoelL

Comment: @JackNavaRow a que te refieres exactamente?

Comment: al cargar un valor en el PATH wen windows tienes que cerrar la terminal y volverla a abrir